# How to Batch Rename Files

Tags: windows, batch, rename

With Windows, I am trying to rename multiple files with a naming convention of  "**`Name (2016)`**" to be to "**`2016 - Name`**", instead.

I've taken my stab at writing a PowerShell script but I'm having some trouble and would like to ask for help with this task due to my lack of having a full understanding of the syntax, etc.

The script below does not work because of "`\(.*\)`" being intended to be "whatever is inside the parenthesis" I think...

### My Work (doesn't work)

```
get-childitem | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("\(.*\)", "") }
```

The idea I have in mind is to somehow set the a variable to whatever is inside the parenthesis suck as "**`Name (x)`**" then rename that to "**`x - Name`**". I'm lost and need help but that's my work.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. You're trying to use a regular expression (regex). In that case the parenthesis are used to delimit a group and are not literals. You could use something like [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VNB0ri/1) to visualize what your regex does (I linked a version which would use literal parenthesis. In addition you would (right now) just remove that portion from the file name. Furthermore you would have to use `-replace` rather than `.replace` as from what I know the first one doesn't support regular expressions. [See also](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-regex.html).

Comment: Slaw - What's the status on this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you showed your work and no one else has taken a stab at it, I've whipped up the below `Batch` script just as the `Batch` tag on your question indicates you're looking for a solution.

Be sure to set the folder path of the `SET SrcDir=` variable below where the files exist. Based on your provided examples of the file names, I tested and this worked with 100% accuracy from my side.

If you're looking for something further, please provide further detail such all full file name examples.

### Example Batch Script

```
@ECHO ON

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET SrcDir=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test

FOR /F "TOKENS=1-3 DELIMS=() " %%A IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%SrcDir%\* (*)*"') DO (
    SET "part1=%%~A" 
    SET "part2=%%~B" 
    SET "part3=%%~C"
    REN "%SrcDir%\!part1! (!part2!)!part3!" "!part2! - !part1!!part3!"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [REN](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)